# Pivot Table with Single Timeline for multiple date columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a Pivot Table from a cube that **has multiple date columns** on it (New, Sale Made, Revenue Recognized). I'm aggregating by a dimension (Level in this case, but could be just about any dimension) and I'd like to provide only 1 Timeline slicer and by selecting a date range in the slicer, adjust counts based on the different date columns.

I've tried the Data Model Date Table trick from the Common timeline for multiple date fields, but I am mentally missing a step to follow so I haven't been able **to link multiple dates to the same date** in that for a slicer.

Has anyone else successfully done something like this before that can share additional steps to what I might be missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Multidimensional ot Tabular cube? Or are you using Power Pivot to build a model in Excel without Analysis Services cubes on a server?

Comment: You can create multiple connections from date fields to the date dimension. One of them will be active, the others will be inactive. The date slicer will filter active connection directly. For inactive connections, you can use DAX function USERELATIONSHIP. For example, https://radacad.com/userelationship-or-role-playing-dimension-dealing-with-inactive-relationships-in-power-bi